# How to rotate 90 degree camera control angle rotate left,right side in three.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js

I created 2 buttons `left` and `right`. if I click `left button` camera rotate 90 degrees each time. I called `leftMode` function. my camera rotate does not work. How to do this rotate angle 90 degree?. Please tell, What mistake in my code?

```
camera3D = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(angle, width / height, near, far);
camera3D.position.set(0, 10, 500);

/* Floor  */
        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(10000, 10000, 10, 10);
        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x444444
        });
        var floor = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        floor.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
        floor.position.set(0, 0, 0);
        floor.rotation.x = Math.PI / 2;
        floor.castShadow = true;
        scene3D.add(floor);

        renderer3D.setClearColor(0x81aff9);
        renderer3D.setSize(width, height);

        controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera3D, renderer3D.domElement);
        canvas3D.appendChild(renderer3D.domElement);
        controls.rotateSpeed = 0.75;
        controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;

this.leftMode = function(){

            console.log(camera3D.rotation);
            console.log(camera3D.position);

            //camera3D.position.x = 500 * Math.cos( 0 );
            //camera3D.position.y = camera3D.position.y;
            //camera3D.position.z = camera3D.position.z;

            //camera3D.rotation.order = (2 * Math.PI) + camera3D.rotation.x;

            //camera3D.position.x = (2 * Math.PI) + camera3D.rotation.x;

            camera3D.rotation.x = camera3D.rotation.x + 90*Math.PI/180;
        }
```

Comment: Hi karthik, If you want rotate you need radius,cos and sin calculation. try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27095251/how-to-rotate-a-three-perspectivecamera-around-on-object

Comment: can u add in jsfiddle?

Comment: yes, I added.@SandipND

Comment: if I click the left button, the camera rotates 90-degree left side direction. How to do this? please, any suggestion example.@SandipND

Comment: Try to rotate your camera around y-axis instead of x-axis.

Comment: I used left side 90 direction this code `camera3D.position.x   = camera3D.position.x +  radius * Math.cos( angle );`  Here radius value 500, angle value 90.is it correct? @prisoner849